# Removing first elements of a list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, element

my problem is how to remove first elements of a list until an element (first occurrence).
The list can have repeated elements.

E.g.

```
?- L = [a, b, c, a, c, d], remove_elements(c, L, Result).
Result = [c, a, c, d].
```

What I have so far is this:

```
remove_elements(Element, [], []).
remove_elements(Element, [Element|Tail], [Tail]).
remove_elements(Element, [Head|Tail], [Tail]) :-
    Head \== Element,
    remove_elements(Element, Tail, Tail).
```

I cannot use any library.

If the `Element` is in the first position, the solution is correct but if it's in the middle it fails.

Thanks

Comment: `Tail` is already a list the way you have it used in this context. So you don't want `[Tail]`. That would be a list consisting of a single list element.

Comment: Can you use append/3 and member/2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Just little corrections, be careful with unification.

```
remove_elements(Element, [], []).
remove_elements(Element, [Element|Tail], [Element|Tail]).
remove_elements(Element, [Head|Tail], List) :- 
                Head \== Element, remove_elements(Element, Tail, List).
```

> Terms S and T are unifiable if:
>
> - S a T are identical constants
> - S a T are (free) variables (S and T are made equal (they co-refer))
> - S is a variable, T is a term ≠ variable (term T is substituted to variable S)
> - T is a variable, S is a term ≠ variable (term S is substituted to variable T)
> - S a T are compound terms (with identical main functor, corresponding arguments are unifiable)

Examples:

```
?- f(X,a(b,c)) = f(d,a(Y,c)).
```

X = d, Y = b.

```
?- f(X,a(b,c)) = f(Y,a(Y,c)).
```

X = Y = b

```
?- f(c,a(b,c)) = f(Y,a(Y,c)).
```

false.